# how to completely factory reset my phone without messing it up?

Tags: rom-flashing, factory-reset, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

So basically me, the stupid idiot, rooted my phone using Kingroot. Bad choice. Now I want to completely factory reset my phone. My friend suggested flashing it twice and then resetting it. How do I do it?

Phone:
Samsung Galaxy S3 mini

Model:
GT-I8190

Version:
4.1.2

Baseband version:
I8190XXAMG4

Kernel Version;:
3. 0. 31 - 1332988
se.infra@SEP-110 #2
SMP PREEMPT Sun Jul 28 14:54:47
KST 2013

Build number:
JZO54K.I8190XXAMG4

Comment: >My friend suggested flashing it twice - It is useless. You only need to do this once.

Comment: Flashing what? You need to flash stock firmware and root will be gone and all data